# Text file for DB settings cannot be created

Tags: java, swing, launch4j, advanced-installer

I create an Library Management System Application in Java Swing, and I created the executable file using **launch 4j**. Then I created an installer using **Advanced Installer 10**. When I am running my application a text file is created for saving the database settings. But when I run the application which is installed by my installer, then the file is not created.

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: It probably has somthing to do with the code of your application. My crystal ball thinks it's at line 425.

Comment: 1) *"Yours Faithfully,
 
Satheesh"*  That amount to 3 lines of noise.  Leave it out in future. (Edit your profile to show your name, if it is that important to you) 2) *"it is very urgent."*  Then I suggest you hire some help at 'urgent' rates.  Voting to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an urgent matter that will be of little interest to future visitors.

Comment: Since it's urgent, we're probably too late to help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a simple permission problem, you should store user specific files in a sub directory of `System.getProperty("user.home");`. Configuring such permissions inside the installation folder may be possible with that installer compiler.